# Rails custom route using another models id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to create a custom route such as 'photos/:user_id/:photo_id' for showing each photo.
In my routes file I have;

```
get 'photos/:user_id/:photo_id' => 'photos#show', :as => 'user_photo'
```

and `rake routes` gives me

```
user_photo GET       /photos/:user_id/:photo_id(.:format)   photos#show
```

Edit;

Now when I link to a photo using `link_to 'some photo', user_photo_path(@photo,@user)` I just get the following error

```
Processing by PhotosController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"8", "photo_id"=>"8"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 8  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Photo without an ID:
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:402:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:68:in `find'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
   () Users/batman/code/myapp/app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:73:in `set_photo'
```

Comment: try `user_photo_path(photo_id: @photo.id, user_id: @photo.user_id)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add it to params:

```
link_to 'some photo', user_photo_path(@photo.user, @photo)
```

The second error is caused by the way you are looking for a photo. Most likely you do:

```
photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
```

If that's the case you need either to change `params[:id]` to `parmas[:photo_id]` (may brake other actions if this is done in `before_filter` or change your route to:

```
get 'photos/:user_id/:id' => 'photos#show', :as => 'user_photo'
```

Comment: `user_id` available in `@photo` variable

Comment: Your use of `/id` will cause an issue here bud!

Comment: Nice one - was going to recommend putting up the controller too

Comment: that's working now thanks, though I don't understand why using :photo_id causes the error and :id doesn't...?

Comment: @raphael_turtle - You have `set_photo` before_filter in your controller which is using `params[:id]`. This filter is run before the show action, which results in `Photo.find(nil)` - which is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was writing this answer, so I'll continue

--

**Routes**

[Shallow nesting](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) could be a better way to do it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do 
    resources :photos, shallow: true #-> /user/photos/:id
end
```

--

**Find**

The problem you have (had) is that although you're sending the right params, your controller will likely not be able to build a model with the code you have.

`BroiStatse` mentioned you should change `Photo.find(params[:id])` - the reason for this is that when you use `Model.find ___`, you're telling the `Model` to look up the `primary key` in your datatable based on the values you pass to it

Using `params[:id]` is fine if you have the `id` param set (as it is most of the time). However, you don't have it set, leading to your controller being unable to find the record:

```
Parameters: {"user_id"=>"8", "photo_id"=>"8"}
```

These are the params you're receiving - your error is thus:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Photo without an ID

Basically means you've not a param set for the `find` method. To fix this, you should use the `photo_id` param:

```
#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
def show
    photo = Photo.find params[:photo_id]
end
```

--

**Params**

When you request a controller action in your application, you'll basically be sending Rails a series of `params` which it can then use in the `controller`.

These `params` are part of a `hash`, which you'll be able to call with `params[:id]` etc:

[image]